# Node.js Mongodb graphql

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I have started a project that in using node.js and express and it's connected to a mongodb, this database has three collections (Participants, Houses, and activities), one participant can have one house and any activities! I have already done the query in graphql for each one, but I don't know how I can do the query and retrieve the relations between them. For example how I can know with participants are on a determined house...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the GraphQL documentation

GraphQL documentation out there tends to focus on queries, less on mutations, less on defining a schema, even less on setting up a server, and even less less on binding the server to an actual database.

```
type participant{
  _id: String
  title: String
  participantId:String
  ........
  house : house
}

type house{
      _id: String
      title: String
      houseId:String
      ........
      activities : [activity]
    }

type activity{
  _id: String
  name: String
  content: String
  post: Post
}
```

This is sample model, you can design schema as per your requirement

Now you can try query like this

```
query {
  participants{
    _id
    title
    }
   house {
     _id
     houseId
    comments {
      _id
      postId
      content
    }
  }
}
```

This is sample query format

Comment: My atual schema is this:

Answer (score 0):

My schema is:

```
type Participant {
        _id: ID!,
        CodP: String!,
        User: String!,
        Birth: Date,
        Country: String,
        Email: String,
        ApplyDate: Date,
        LUG: String,
        Status: String,
        Control: String,
        CodH: House,
        CodA: [Activitie],
        createAt: Date,
        updateAt: Date,
    }

    type Activitie {
        _id: ID!,
        CodA: String,
        Day: String,
        StartTime: Date,
        EndTime: Date,
        Where: String,
        Name: String,
        Description: String, 
    }

    type House {
        _id: ID!,
        CodH: String,
        Name: String,
        Onwer: String,
        Address: String,
        Local: String,
        Contact1: String,
        Contact2: String,
        Contact3: String,
        Email: String,
        URL: URL,
        CoordDD: String,
        CoordDMS: String,
        URLGoogleMaps: URL,
        IMG: String,
        Group: String,
        ImgGoogleMaps: String,
        I1: String,
        Info: String,
        I2: String,
        N1: String,
        I3: String,
        N2: String,
        I4: String,
        N3: String,
        I5: String,
        N4: String,
        I6: String,
        N5: String,
        I7: String,
        N6: String,
        I8: String,
        N7: String,
        I9: String,
        N8: String,
        I10: String,
        N9: String,
        I11: String,
        Final: String
    }

    type Query {
        getParticipant(_id: ID): Participant
        getParticipantAll: [Participant]
        getActivitie(_id: ID): Activitie
        getActivitieAll: [Activitie]
        getHouse(_id: ID): House
        getHouseAll: [House]
        getHouseCod(CodH: String): [House]
    }
```

But my problem in the Resolver, simples one i can do it, for example:

```
import House from '../../models/House';

export default {
  getHouse: (_, { _id }) => House.findById(_id),
  getHouseCod: (_, { CodH }) => House.find({CodH}),
  // createdAt vai permitir ordenar pela data de criação //
  getHouseAll: () => House.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 }),
};
```